# graphlab create sframe how to get SArray median

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis, graphlab

I'm studying graphlab create
with

```
data=graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('test.csv')
```

im trying to get median of one of columns

```
data_train.fillna(('Credit_History',data_train['Credit_History'].median()))
```

but I got error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-50ed3eb09dcc> in <module>()
----> 1 data_train.fillna(('Credit_History',data_train['Credit_History'].median()))

AttributeError: 'SArray' object has no attribute 'median'
```

data.show() will show median of this column though
anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: What is the `data_train` object? Is it also an `Sframe`? Is it supposed to be `data`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what your trying to do. Sframe doesn't have a default median function. I would improvise like this:

```
import numpy as np
data_train.fillna('Credit_History', np.median(data_train['Credit_History']))
```

Answer (score 1):

`SArray` doesn't have a median method. The best way to get the median is through the `sketch_summary` method, then `quantile`. More info on the sketch summary at

https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.Sketch.html

```
import numpy as np
import graphlab as gl

sf = gl.SFrame(np.random.rand(100))

sketch = sf['X1'].sketch_summary()
median = sketch.quantile(0.5)
```

Comment: thanks this works too, im wondering why graphlab has mean() method but no median()